# What is the RubyonRails syntax to add target="_parent" to a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, target

I am a designer not a coder and while I can hack .PHP i have been given a quick job of putting some design around a Ruby app. Never looked at Ruby before so sorry for the very basic Q.

How to I add target="_parent" to this url?  What I have tried so far has borked the app.

```
<%= link_to 'Click to go here', 'http://www.url.ie/forum/' %>
```

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to 'Click to go here', 'http://www.url.ie/forum/', :target => "_parent" %>
```

After the link text and url, the hash (ie. `:key => 'value'`) followed would be transformed to attributes of the tag!

FYI, `link_to` could accept a block too:

```
<%= link_to 'http://www.url.ie/forum', :target => "_parent" do %>
  <%= image_tag "forum.png", :alt => "" %>
  anything here would be the content inside the `a` tag!
  You could also insert images here!
<% end %>
```